# Visual Studio project template not performing substitution in one file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, project-template

I'm creating a Visual Studio project template as described in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185311.aspx). This involves using `$tokens$` in files (cs/csproj/xml/etc) which are substituted when the template is used.

However this substitution is not happening for one of my files.

Why isn't it applying to this file?

Answer (score 0):

Not all file types (determined by extension) are supported.

For example, if you have an XML document named `App.manifest` then substitution will not be applied.

To get around this, rename the file to end in a supported extension (eg. `App.manifest.xml`), then update the `.vstemplate` file to apply the desired name when the template is used.

In this example the `ProjectItem` node would resemble:

```
<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true"
             TargetFileName="App.manifest">App.manifest.xml</ProjectItem>
```